# ipad web app not adjustd for portrait mode, uiwebview,

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, safari, portrait, iphone-web-app

I've a web application for iphone/ipad. When I view it in mobile safari it appears good both in landscape and portrait mode. But when I open it in my own ipad web app (under uiwebview), it appears good in landscape mode, but contents are cut-off in portrait mode.

How to fix it. Am i supposed to fix it on server side, or in ipad application?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in Mobile Safari and not in your wrapper app using `UIWebView`, it is possible that the problem comes from the application, and that your webview is not properly resized when the device rotates to landscape.
Try setting the webview's [autoresizingMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) as follow in your view setup code :

```
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

or, if you defined your webview in Interface Builder, use the "size inspector" to set the appropriate autoresizing mask (every red line must be selected in the resizing diagram).